# Server.crt issues on AWS Lightsail after following Let's Encrypt tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, apache2, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I'm having issues after following this tutorial on setting up SSL on a Wordpress Lightsail server. I followed their tutorial (https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress) to the 'T' but at the end, I keep getting the following error: 
[image]

When I look in the apache2/conf folder the server.ctr and server.key file names are both red, and I have no clue what that means, but I feel like they're connected. Any help would be appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Please check if this is related to your problem(file permission issue): https://serverfault.com/questions/885727/ssl-certificate-file-permissions

Comment: I don't think this is an access issue, the error says it doesn't exist or is empty. There's no EACCES in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to go in, unlink and then relink them. I think it was something that had to do with the permissions either on those links or the files they linked to.

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf
sudo rm server.crt
sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/*filename*/fullchain.pem server.crt
```

Same thing with the privkey.pem/server.key and then those file names went from red to blue, I restarted server using the script below and all was good!

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

Where I found the answer: https://community.bitnami.com/t/chown-cannot-dereference-opt-bitnami-apache2-conf-server-crt-no-such-file-or-directory/58839/12